# Is it true that $\int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/2})\big)^2\,dk = \frac{7}2\zeta(3)$?

Tags: integration, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, zeta-functions, elliptic-functions

Define the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) as,

$$K(k) = \tfrac{\pi}{2}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,1,\,k^2\right)$$

**Part I.** From the link above, we find some of the evaluations below,

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 K(k^{1/1})\,dk &= 2C\\ 
\int_0^1 K(k^{1/2})\,dk &= 2\\ 
\int_0^1 K(k^{1/3})\,dk &= \frac34(2C+1) \\ 
\int_0^1 K(k^{1/4})\,dk &= \frac{20}9 \\ 
\int_0^1 K(k^{1/5})\,dk &= \frac5{64}(18C+13)
\end{aligned}$$

and so on (?) where $C$ is ***Catalan's constant***.

**Part II.** On a hunch, I decided to check 2nd powers. It turns out that,

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/2})\big)^2\,dk &= \frac{7}2\zeta(3)\\ 
\int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/4})\big)^2\,dk &= \frac{7}2\zeta(3)+1\\ 
\int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/6})\big)^2\,dk &= \frac{231}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{51}{32}\\ 
 \int_0^1 \big(K(k^{1/8})\big)^2\,dk &= \frac{238}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{881}{432}\\ 
\end{aligned}$$

and so on (?) where $\zeta(3)$ is ***Apery's constant***.

**Question:** Does the pattern of Part I (involving Catalan's constant) and Part II (involving Apery's constant) really go on forever? What is the closed-form?

Comment: It seems there is for 3rd powers as well. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103805/).

Comment: Interesting. Using Mathematica I have found other conjectural examples of integrals and families of series where a seemingly infinite sequence of similar results occur. When higher $\zeta(2n+1)$ and $\beta(2n)$  constants appear (perhaps also in this case for cubes and higher) they normally appear in repeating patterns along side all their smaller siblings.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Did you mean $\int_{0}^{1} (K(k^{1/2}))^{2} = \frac{7}{2}\zeta(3) + 1  $ ? This seems to check out numerically

Comment: @MaxMuller In the OP, $k$ is the *modulus* of the elliptic function defined by the hypergeometric function (first equation). You probably used a program which takes the *parameter* $m=k^2$ as the argument of the function ([as in the Wolfram Language, for example](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html)). Then, your numerical result corresponds to the second equation of Part II.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set
$$
\theta_2(q):=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{(n+1/2)^2}\textrm{, }\theta_3(q):=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}q^{n^2}\textrm{, }\theta_4(q):=\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty}(-1)^nq^{n^2}.
$$
Then
$$
\theta_2(q)^2=\frac{2kK}{\pi}\textrm{, }\theta_3(q)^2=\frac{2K}{\pi}\textrm{, }\theta_4(q)^2=\frac{2k'K}{\pi}
$$
and
$$
\frac{dk}{dr}=-\frac{k(k')^2K(k)^2}{\pi\sqrt{r}}.
$$
Thus
$$
I=\int^{1}_{0}K\left(\sqrt{k}\right)^2dk=2\int^{1}_{0}K(k)^2kdk=-2\int^{0}_{\infty}K(k)^2k\frac{k(k')^2K(k)^2}{\pi\sqrt{r}}dr=
$$
$$
=2\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{(kk')^2K(k)^4}{\pi\sqrt{r}}dr=2\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\pi^2\theta_2(q)^4}{4K^2}\frac{\pi^2\theta_4(q)^4}{4K^2}\frac{K^4}{\pi\sqrt{r}}dr=
$$
$$
=\frac{\pi^3}{8}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\theta_2(q)^4\theta_4(q)^4}{\sqrt{r}}dr
$$
But $q=e^{-\pi\sqrt{r}}$. Hence $dq=\frac{-\pi q}{2\sqrt{r}}dr$. Hence
$$
I=\frac{-\pi^3}{8}\int^{0}_{1}\theta_2(q)^4\theta_4(q)^4\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}\frac{2\sqrt{r}}{\pi q}dq=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\int^{1}_{0}\theta_2(q)^4\theta_4(q)^4\frac{dq}{q}.
$$
From the above integral we conclude easily that
$$
I=\frac{\pi^3}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}\theta_2\left(e^{-2\pi t}\right)^4\theta_4\left(e^{-2\pi t}\right)^4dt.
$$

We set now
$$
P(z):=\theta_2(q)^4\theta_4(q)^4\textrm{, }q=e^{2\pi i z}\textrm{, }Im(z)>0
$$
The function $P(z)$ is a weight 4 modular form in $\Gamma_1(4)$. The space $M_4(\Gamma_1(4))$ has dimension 3, with no cusp forms i.e. $dim(S_4(\Gamma_1(4))=0$ and $dim(E_4(\Gamma_1(4))=3$.

Consider now the functions
$$
E_{2k}(q):=2\zeta(2k)\left(1+\frac{2}{\zeta(1-2k)}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sigma_{2k-1}(n)q^n\right),
$$
where $\sigma_{\nu}(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^{\nu}$, $\zeta(s)$ being the Riemann zeta function. The functions $E_{2k}(q)$ are the classical Eisenstein series of weight $2k$, $k-$positive integer. For the present case we get $k=2$ and we will use the property $E_{2k}(q)-lE_{2k}(q^l)$ is a base element of $M_{2k}(\Gamma_1(N))$, when $l|N$.

Also in [1] I have proven that if $q=e^{2\pi i z}$, $Im(z)>0$, then
$$
H_k(q):=\frac{\pi^k}{k!}\left(\left(2-2^k\right)|B_{k}|+4ki^kF_{k}(q)\right),
$$
$$
F_k(q):=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\sigma^{*}_{k-1}(n)q^n,
$$
where $\sigma^{*}_{\nu}(n):=\sum_{d|n,d-odd}d^{\nu}$, $B_{k}$ are the Bernoulli numbers, $k-$even positive integher, are modular forms of the space $M_k\left(\Gamma_1(2)\right)$, where
$$
\Gamma_1(N):=\left\{\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 a\textrm{  }b\\
 c\textrm{  }d
\end{array}\right]:a,b,c,d\in\textbf{Z}\textrm{, }ab-cd=1\textrm{, }a,d\equiv1(N)\textrm{ and }b,c\equiv 0(N)
\right\}.
$$
By this way and from the fact that $P(z)$ is in dimension 3 space, comparing coefficients, we have
$$
P(z)=C_1\left(E_4(q)-4E_4(q^4)\right)+C_2H_4(q)+C_3H_4(-q),
$$
where
$$
C_1=-\frac{14}{5\pi^4}\textrm{, }C_2=\frac{28}{\pi^4}\textrm{, }C_3=-\frac{92}{5\pi^4}.
$$

Hence writing
$$
P(z)=a_P(0)+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_P(n)q^n,
$$
we get
$$
a_P(0)=0
$$
and for $n=1,2,\ldots$, we get 
$$
a_P(n)=-\frac{224}{15}\sigma_3(n)+\frac{896}{15}\sigma_3\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+\frac{56}{3}\sigma^{*}_3(n)-\frac{184}{15}(-1)^n\sigma^{*}_3(n)
$$
The Dirichlet series $L(s)$ coresponding to $a_P(n)$ are
$$
L(s)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_P(n)}{n^s}
$$
and the function
$$
\Lambda_P(s):=\left(\frac{2}{i}\right)^4\int^{+\infty}_{0}P(it)t^{s-1}dt=G(s)\left(\frac{2}{i}\right)^4\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_P(n)}{n^s},
$$
where $G(s)=(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)$ (here $\Gamma$ means the Euler's Gamma function), have the property (analytic continuation) via the functional equation
$$
\Lambda_P(s)=4^{2-s}\Lambda_P(4-s)
$$
Hence we want to find $\Lambda_P(1)=4\Lambda_P(3)$. But
$$
\Lambda_P(s)=2^4(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)[-\frac{224}{15}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sigma_3(n)}{n^s}+\frac{896}{15}4^{-s}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sigma_3(n)}{n^{s}}+
$$
$$
+\frac{56}{3}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sigma^{*}_3(n)}{n^s}-\frac{184}{15}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n\sigma^{*}_3(n)}{n^s}]=
$$
$$
=2^4(2\pi)^{-s} \Gamma(s)[-\frac{224}{15}\zeta(s-3)\zeta(s)+\frac{896}{15}4^{-s}\zeta(s-3)\zeta(s)+
$$
$$
+\frac{56}{3}2^{-s}(-8+2^s)\zeta(s-3)\zeta(s)
-\frac{184}{15}2^{-s}\left(2^{1-s}-1\right)(-8+2^s)\zeta(s-3)\zeta(s)]. 
$$
Hence
$$
\Lambda_P(3)=\lim_{s\rightarrow 3}\Lambda_P(s)=2^4 (2\pi)^{-3} \Gamma(3)7\zeta(3).
$$
Hence
$$
\Lambda_P(1)=4\Lambda_P(3)=\frac{28\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}=2\cdot 2^{4}I \pi^{-3}
$$
and consequently
$$
I=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{2}.
$$
QED

REFERENCES

[1]: N.D. Bagis. ''Evaluations of certain theta functions in Ramanujan theory of alternative modular bases''. arXiv:1511.03716v2 [math.GM] 6 Dec 2017.

Comment: A basis of the weight $4$ Eisenstein series for $\Gamma_1(N)$ are the $E_4(\alpha_j(z))$ with $\alpha_j \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $\Gamma_1(N) \subset \alpha_j^{-1} SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \alpha_j$ ie. $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \bigcup_{j=1}^J \alpha_j \Gamma_1(N) \alpha_j^{-1}$ which contains things like $E_4(z+1/N)$. To evaluate $\int_0^\infty y^{s-1} E_4(iy+1/N)dy$ we need to look at $L(s,\chi)L(s-3,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_3(n) \chi(n) n^{-s}$

Comment: I don't know much about modular forms, but I think that the only shadowed point is the choise of $E_{4}(q)-4E_4(q^4)$ as a base element of $M_4(\Gamma_1(4))$. The $H_4(q)$ and $H_4(-q)$ are explained in [1]. Also if the dimension of the space is 3 and possess no cusp forms. A base ellement of $M_4(\Gamma)$ is also a base element of $M_4(\Gamma_1(4))$.

Answer (score 11):

In part I, the integrals can be written as
\begin{equation}
  I_n=n\int_0^1x^{n-1}K(x)\,dx
\end{equation}
The moments of the elliptic integrals seem to be well described in the literature (see
[here](https://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/emoments.pdf) for example)
Denoting $K_n$ and $E_n$ the moments of order $n$ of $K$ and $E$,
\begin{equation}
  K_n=\int_0^1x^nK(x)\,dx; \quad  E_n=\int_0^1x^nE(x)\,dx
\end{equation}
Then $I_n=nK_{n-1}$
the following recursions are derived:
\begin{equation}
  K_{n+2}=\frac{nK_n+E_n}{n+2};\quad E_n=\frac{K_n+1}{n+2}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
  K_0=2C;\quad E_0=C+\frac{1}{2};\quad K_1=1;\quad E_1=\frac{2}{3}
\end{equation}
which explains the observed pattern.

In part II, integrals can be written as
\begin{equation}
  J_{2p}=2p\int_0^1 x^{2p-1}K^2(x)\,dx
\end{equation}
Denoting the moment of order $n$ of $K^2$,
\begin{equation}
  {}_2K_n=\int_0^1x^nK^2(x)\,dx
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
  J_{2p}=2p\,_2K_{2p-1}
\end{equation}
In [Moments of products of elliptic integrals](http://people.sutd.edu.sg/~james_wan/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/mkint.pdf)
by J.G. Wan, Theorem 2 expresses that, when $p$ is odd, the p-th moments of $K'^2,
E'^2, K'E', K^2, E^2$ and $KE$ are expressible as $a+b\zeta(3)$. Moreover, the
moments of $K^2$ satisfy a recursion
\begin{equation}
  (n+1)^3 {}_2K_{n+2}-2n\left( n^2+1 \right) {}_2K_n+(n-1)^3 {}_2K_{n-2}=2
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}
 J_{2p+4}=\frac{p+2}{2\left( p+1 \right)^3}+\frac{\left( p+2 \right)\left( 2p+1 \right)\left( 2p^2+2p+1 \right)}{2\left( p+1 \right)^4}J_{2p+2}-\frac{p^2\left( p+2 \right)}{(p+1)^3}J_{2p}
\end{equation} 
In the linked paper, a method is given to obtain ${}_2K_1$ and ${}_2K_3$ using a theorem by Zudilin which express them in terms of a ${}_7F_6$ hypergeometric function.