# Evaluate two integrals involving $\operatorname{Li}_3,\operatorname{Li}_4$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration, polylogarithm

I need to evaluate
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} 
\frac{\displaystyle{\operatorname{Re}\left ( 
\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  \right )
\ln^2\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  }}{x(1+x^2)} \text{d}x.$$
$\operatorname{Li}_n(.)$ denotes the "**Polylogarithms**".
Numerical tests derived
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} 
\frac{\displaystyle{\operatorname{Re}\left ( 
\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  \right )
\ln^2\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  }}{x(1+x^2)} \text{d}x
=\operatorname{Im}\left[\operatorname{Li}_3\left ( \frac{1+i}{2}  \right )
\right]^2+\frac{1911}{4096}\zeta(3)^2 +\frac{413}{1536}\zeta(3)\ln^32
-\frac{721}{6144}\pi^2\zeta(3)\ln2-\frac{41}{1536}\pi^2\ln^42
+\frac{77}{12288}\pi^4\ln^22+\frac{7}{256}\ln^62.$$

---

I checked this
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} 
\frac{\displaystyle{\operatorname{Re}\left ( 
\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  \right )
\ln^3\left ( \frac{1+x}{2}  \right )  }}{x(1+x^2)} \text{d}x
=3\operatorname{Im}
\left [ \operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1+i}{2}  \right ) \right ]^2
-\frac{343\pi^4\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right ) }{49152}
+\frac{693\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right )^2}{256}
-\frac{5\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right )}{256}\ln^42
+\frac{25\pi^2\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{1}{2}  \right )}{2048}\ln^22
-\frac{117649\pi^8}{2831155200}-\frac{\ln^82}{3072}
+\frac{5\pi^2\ln^62}{12288}-\frac{1061\pi^4\ln^42}{2949120} 
+\frac{343\pi^6\ln^22}{2359296}.$$

Comment: Where did you find this monster?

Comment: I suggest math overflow for this integral.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Such integral (i.e. level $4$ weight $6$) will be routinely evaluated by a [new version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763243) of `MZIntegrate`, which will be released soon. But I think an more elementary way is possible judging on its simple result.

Comment: @pisco How to prove $\int_{2-\sqrt{3} }^{1} 
\frac{\log\left ( \frac{1-x}{\sqrt{2x} }  \right )
\left [ \frac{\pi}{2}\log\left ( \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{2x} }  \right ) 
-\operatorname{Ti}_2\left ( \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{2x} }  \right )  \right ]  }{1+x^2} 
\text{d}x=\frac{1}{2}C^2$?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory No idea, this seems quite nontrivial.

Comment: @pisco Any way to show $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} }\ln\Big[
K(\sin x)^2+K(\cos x)^2 \Big]\text{d}x
=\pi\ln(\pi)$?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory Your second integral can be done by contour integration. Where did you get these problems?

Comment: @pisco Which is the second integral?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2} }\ln\Big[ K(\sin x)^2+K(\cos x)^2 \Big]\text{d}x$

Comment: @pisco Is it possible to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1}\vartheta_2(q)^6\vartheta_4(q)^2
\text{d}x,q=e^{-\pi x}$?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory Using technique similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805720. If $\vartheta_2^6(2z) \vartheta_4^2(2z)$ is modular of weight $4$ to some congruence subgroup, and there is no cusp form, then your integral can be written as Dirichlet-L functions. If there are cusp form, then things become more difficult.

Comment: @pisco $\frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{2+x^2}\right)  }{
(1+x^2)\sqrt{2+x^2} } \text{d}x
+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{5+x^2}\right)}{(4+x^2)\sqrt{5+x^2} }
\text{d} x
=\frac{\pi}{4}\left ( \arctan\left ( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6} }  \right ) 
+3\arctan\left ( \sqrt{\frac{2}{3} }  \right )  \right ) 
-\frac{\pi^2}{16}$?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory Yes, it's true.